# Cognitive Services - Bing Grammar Check API v7.0

Tags: azure, bing-api

I have built a feature for grammar check and am trying it with some different AI APIs.
I am trying to get it to work with Bing API and am using dev.cognitive to test but am always getting permission denied: [https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5f7d486e04d2430193e1ca8f760cd7ed/operations/56e73036cf5ff81048ee6727/consol](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5f7d486e04d2430193e1ca8f760cd7ed/operations/56e73036cf5ff81048ee6727/console)e

These are the steps I took:
 - Created a Resource and Cognitive Services service
 - Copied the Key 1 
 - Accessed the link above to test it and I am getting:

```
Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2019 18:51:32 GMT
Content-Length: 224

{"error":{"code":"401","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."}}
```

The query parameters are:

- mode: proof
- mkt: en-us

  I appreciate if someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: In which region you created the service

Comment: It's created in east-us @Sajeetharan

Comment: did that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had created a Cognive Services service as a multi-service resource and there they didn't make me specify I was using this for Bing Spell Check.
I created a new one but this time as a Single Service Resource: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesBingSearch-v7
and selected the correct price tier for what I needed (either S1 or S2) and it now works.
My previous multiservice cognive service had an endpoint ending like this: .api.cognitive.microsoft.com/
and for this purpose, it will only work when you have an endpoint like this: .cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0

Also wanted to give thanks to @Sajeetharan for giving me his time and helping me to get to my resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try replacing the resource Name with the resource you have created? I just tried with a new resource created and it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I tried.. but still getting the same error and if I put the resource name I get no response at all. @Sajeetharan

Comment: that cannot be, can you check the image i posted

Comment: there are my screenshots.. the ones without responce dont show any response after I click on Send.. it should show the json.. https://ibb.co/yWMTNtS
https://ibb.co/5MvkHsd
https://ibb.co/NSjw6dS

Comment: kindly capture the response image and share.

Comment: they are in these links: https://ibb.co/yWMTNtS; https://ibb.co/5MvkHsd; https://ibb.co/NSjw6dS

Comment: i dont see the response pane in those images

Comment: it only shows response for this one: https://ibb.co/5MvkHsd.. the other ones don't show anything when I attempt to send..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202597/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-luana-mayara-fernandes).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the required header `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` is not being passed or it contains the wrong value. You can find a full working sample in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-spell-check/quickstarts/csharp

Comment: I have provided the key they gave me as Ocp key.. unless there is a different one... thank you though